# Colour a row based on value of cell being a date before today

Tags: api, google-sheets

I currently use some code provided by these forums to colour rows based on a value in a cell matching specified criteria.  See script below.

What I need to do is evolve the code to enable me to colour the rows in my spreadsheet based in the value of one of the cells in the row being a date.  If this date is before TODAY then I would like to colour the whole row "RED" for example.  I've tried to tweak what I have but nothing is working - any help would be much appreciated!

```
function onEdit(e) {
    if (e) { 
    var ss = e.source.getActiveSheet();
    var r = e.source.getActiveRange(); 

        if (r.getRow() != 1 && ss.getName() == "Bookings") {
            status = ss.getRange(r.getRow(), 7).getValue();
            rowRange = ss.getRange(r.getRow(),1,1,900);

            if (status == 'Booking - Paid') {
                rowRange.setBackgroundColor("#eb0604");
            } else if (status == 'Booking - Deposit Paid') {
                rowRange.setBackgroundColor("#999999");
            } else if (status == '') { 
                rowRange.setFontColor("#000000");
            }   
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a script to do this! Conditional formatting should do the trick for you.

Here is a custom conditional formatting formula:

```
=AND(($A2 < TODAY()), NOT(ISBLANK($A2)))
```

Here are the results:
[image]

Here is an example Spreadsheet: [Example Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1D8uPJ6RmY-4Ep_WPDLoaVxp5YFJCEHIITFI-TVSWCvo/edit#gid=0)

Comment: any idea on why this isn't working for me? I'm using REGEXEXTRACT in column B to extract the date from Column A. When I use your formula, it doesn't work for me. Here's my Google Sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OZmyUm45nV_17q7YZ2Zye-o_beo6IWtyCUjUc8wCPUE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: None of your dates are before today, so none of them will be highlighted.

Comment: there's a few of them before today's date in Column B, like in B17, B24, and B33.

Comment: It looks to be highlighted to me, maybe the range wasn't covering those cells?